# How to validate Password and Username for website in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, passwords

I have a simple login website, which is my first website project in Visual Studio 2015. I have successfully created a SQL database which contains user information like Username, Password, Email and Country, and I have also successfully created a user registration page where a new user can input there details and these details will be added to the database. This all works fine.

but I have hit a roadblock while attempting to validate the Username and Password against the stored values in the row containing the User data  in the SQLdatabase to give the user access to the member only pages.

Heres my code snippet for when the user click the login button.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MembersConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string checkUser = "SELECT * FROM Members where Username= '" + TextBoxSignUser.Text + "' and Password= '" + TextBoxSignPass.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(checkUser, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

I know what I need to do is probably something like this pseudocode below, but I am unsure how to go about validating this information against stored values in the database.

```
if ("Username" and "Password" == the value of Username and Password TextBox.Text)
{
        Response.Write("Sign in successful");
        Response.Redirect("MemberTestPage.aspx");
}
else
{
Response.Write("Details incorrect, Please try again")
}
```

Comment: You should not try to write code concerning users and passwords until you fully understand the concepts of SQL-Injection and Password hashing.

Comment: Hi Peter, this example is just for a simple login program to practice with, no sensitive data will be stored in the database until I know that I can store the information securely. I have already begun learning about  password hashing techniques and how to avoid SQL injection. 
I appreciate the advice nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Fill the data-table using data adapter one you get the data into a data-table you can get the return values of the query and match the parameters

```
        DataTable Dt = new Datatable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.rows.count > 0 ) 
        {
           //MATCH FOUND
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use like..

```
string query= "SELECT * FROM Members where Username= 'usr' and Password= 'pwd'";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    MySqlDataAdapter objda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet objDs = new DataSet();
    objda.Fill(objDs);
    if(objDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
    {
          Response.Write("Sign in successful");
          Response.Redirect("MemberTestPage.aspx");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do as following without using Datasets,

```
var con = new SqlConnection("your connection string goes here");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Members where Username= 'usr' and Password= 'pwd'", con);
bool result = false;
cmd.Connection.Open();
using (cmd.Connection)
{
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
        result = true;
}
if (result == true)
    // Login successful
else
    // Login failed
```

Answer (score -1):

I think first of all it is better to use ADO.NET libraries for some reasons like best performance and high security. Here is my suggestion. hope to be useful for you:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
...

string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MembersConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Members where Username = @user and Password = @pass";
SqlParameter pUser = new SqlParameter("@user", TextBoxSignUser.Text);
SqlParameter pPass = new SqlParameter("@pass", TextBoxSignPass.Text);
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pUser);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(pPass);

        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                // Successfully signed in
                // Also you can access your fields' value using:
                //    1. its index (e.x. reader[0])
                //    2. or its name: (e.x. reader["Username"])
            }
            else
            {
                // Login failed
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Table] WHERE Username = '{0}' and Password = '{1}'", txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
command = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
  //successfully login
}
else
  //error message
```